# Is Hebrew compulsory to practice Judaism?

Tags: hebrew

I am an atheist and loosely read mi yodeya because I am generally interested in cultures and the technicities of Judaism are fascinating.

A lot of the questions (and especially answers) cite verbatim Hebrew, usually with a translation when it is a citation, but then there are also Hebrew words (written in Hebrew) in commenting sentences.

**Is a conversational knowledge of Hebrew compulsory in order to practice Judaism?** By "compulsory" I mean "everything is in Hebrew so if you do not know it you will not understand a thing" (not "religiously compulsory", but that's a good question as well)

For context, I come culturally from the Catholic world and vernacular languages are used (at least since the mid '60s). Before that the practicants had close to zero understanding of what was going on when the mass was in Latin , thus the changes during that time.

Comment: Are you asking about daily practice or about attaining the ability to discuss daily practice (as on this site)? The forever is much less demanding.

Comment: @magicker72: I was asking about everyday practices of the general population, not advanced studies (it is clear to me that for the latter being fluent in Hebrew is a necessity)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd have to define your terms slightly more precisely, but let's give this a go: the Talmud talks about including "ignoramuses" who didn't speak, or read, Hebrew. (In fact the Talmud says sometimes the Romans installed a high priest who spoke the vernacular (Aramaic) but couldn't understand Hebrew! The experts could still coach the fellow through the rituals, and he'd be okay as long as he listened.)

Now someone has to be read the prayers and scripture in Hebrew in synagogue, but others can just listen along. I would add that the goal has always been to get more people to learn Hebrew; not to keep people locked out of knowledge.

While there's been an explosion of translated material out there, serious expertise of the faith will require stronger Hebrew reading ability. The ordination exams at Yeshiva University, for instance, will put the questions in Hebrew and allow the student to write their answers in either Hebrew or English. (Many American rabbis aren't the greatest at generating spoken Hebrew conversationally, but they do just fine.) There was discussion in the early 1900s about translating the entire canon into English to train American rabbis who could pronounce Hebrew but not really understand it; fortunately, enough became sufficiently Hebrew-literate that this wasn't necessary.

Most broadly, the obligation of Torah study is basically "to the best of your ability." Someone trying to do it at an advanced level is going to need to be able to read Hebrew to get more out of the material -- but that's a broad term.

In an Orthodox Jewish synagogue that assumes many attending don't have a strong background, they'll use a Hebrew-English prayerbook. Many will frequently announce page numbers, or have a device showing you the page number. There are even transliterated prayer books, for those who want to pronounce everything in Hebrew even if they can't read it.

Private prayer can, in theory, be done in English. There are only one or two rare rituals that would require an individual to use the original Hebrew -- it means the rabbi would coach them through three lines, phonetically. (The biggest problem that occurs with said coaching, actually, is that those lines include a couple of [fricative consonants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hebrew_alphabet#Ancient_Hebrew_pronunciation) that adult monolingual English speakers have trouble pronouncing -- a story for another time!)

At the weekly worship, the cantor is up there reading Scripture out of a handwritten Hebrew scroll. If someone can phonetically read two lines of Hebrew, they can be called up to recite the blessing before the cantor reads -- in fact, in a place with lots of neophytes, there will be a card up there with the blessing transliterated into English as well. (On this last point, there was an interesting debate whether you could only participate in the reading ritual if you could make out Hebrew letters. The conclusion, at least among Jews of Central and Eastern European ancestry, is that even that wasn't required.) The cantor reading it, by the way, doesn't necessarily have to know what every word means.

If someone shows up off the street and says "rabbi I'm Jewish by birth but never got much Hebrew", the rabbi will encourage them to show up, say their private prayers either in English or transliterated Hebrew, and maybe step up for fifteen seconds of ritual every so often -- even being given a transliterated card.

Someone who shows up and asks to convert is given a slightly higher bar -- the rabbi should not sign off on this person until confident they are serious about it, and have a high probability of sticking with it. Practically, most will be expected to learn to pronounce Hebrew -- even if slowly-- and learn a handful of common words. (If someone's sincerely trying but just completely hopeless at foreign languages, that's a reasonable call for the rabbi to make.)

Answer (score 2):

No it is not compulsory for practicing Judaism. Hebrew as a conversational language is something that did not exist for a long period of time. "Biblical Hebrew" while it was conversational at one point in time became the language of study and prayer and for most of Jewish history Jews spoke other languages. The modern Hebrew today spoken by Israelis therefore would obviously not be a necessary component of practicing Judaism as this is a recent development and speaking "Biblical Hebrew" conversationally would not have been practical after it fell out of practice as many aspects of language would be missing.